# Leer últimos mensajes ingresados a un txt desde PHP

Tags: php, archivo, fopen

Tengo los siguientes archivos:

`index.php`

```
<section>
  <h2>Comentarios</h2>
  <form action="comentarios.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre completo" required><br>
    <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required><br>
    <textarea name="comentario" placeholder="Comentarios" required cols="20" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="envio" value="Enviar">
  </form>
  <br>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ok'])) {
  include("comentarios.txt");
}
?>
</section>
```

Y `comentarios.php` donde se crea un archivo txt:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['envio'])) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
  $fecha = date("d-m-Y G:i");
  $comentario = $fecha."<br>".
    "<p>Nombre completo: ".$_POST['nombre'].
    "</p><p>Correo: ".$_POST['correo'].
    "</p><p>Mensaje: ".$_POST['comentario']."</p><hr>";

  $archivo = fopen("comentarios.txt", "a+") or die("Error al abrir el archivo");
  fputs($archivo, $comentario);
  fpassthru($archivo);
  fclose($archivo);
  header("Location:unidad3.php?ok");
}

?>
```

Mi intención es que se puedan leer los comentarios justo debajo del formulario. Con lo que hice hasta ahora consigo que se acumulen los comentarios debajo del formulario, pero quisiera que se puedan leer los más recientes primeros y al final los más antiguos. Alguien podría decirme si estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Podrías escribir al inicio del archivo en vez de al final, revisa por ejemplo las respuestas en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1760525/5587982). Pero eso casi siempre supone volver a manejar cada vez todo el contenido del archivo, sobre-escribirlo, etc, con el riesgo de que algo salga mal y pierdas todo. Este tipo de tareas **dinámicas** deberían hacerse mediante una base de datos, no en un archivo.

Comment: Y si antes del `fputs` agregas `rewind($archivo);`, soluciona el problema?

Comment: Lo intenté pero no lo soluciona, Yussef. Gracias igual

Comment: Porque has desechado la idea de hacerlo por Base de Datos??

Comment: Hola Yenn, la consigna indica que hay que hacerlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 2):

Ya logré imprimir los últimos comentarios al principio, como quería. Lo que tenía que hacer era crear un array e invertir los valores a través de un bucle. Dejo el código para el que le sirva.
En el archivo comentarios.php creé las variables y el txt. En el otro archivo, index.php, debajo del formulario abri el archivo en modo lectura y creé un array para que junto a un bucle se pueda ver debajo del formulario los elementos a la inversa.

index.php:

```
<section>
    <h2>Comentarios</h2>
    <form action="unidad3.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required><br>
        <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required><br>
        <textarea name="comentario" placeholder="Comentarios" required cols="20" rows="1"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="envio" value="Enviar mensaje">
    </form>
</section>

<aside>
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        include("comentarios.php");
        
        $txt="comentarios.txt";
        $archivo = fopen($txt, "r") or die("error al abrir el archivo: $txt");

        $vector = file("comentarios.txt");
        $contar_valores = count($vector);

        do {
            echo $vector[$contar_valores-1];
            $contar_valores--;
        } while ($contar_valores >=0);
        

        fclose($archivo);
    }

?>

</aside>
```

comentarios.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['envio'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y G:i");
    $nombre =  $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['comentario'];

    $texto = "<hr>
    <p>Mensaje: $mensaje</p> 
    <p>Correo: $correo</p>
    <p>Nombre completo: $nombre</p>
    <p>Fecha: $fecha</p>
    ";

    $archivo = fopen("comentarios.txt","a+");
    fwrite($archivo, $texto); 
    fclose($archivo);
}
```

?>

También quiero dejar este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/606488/warning-undefined-array-key-24-in-c-xampp-htdocs-on-line-40)
en el que un chico me ayudó a comprender que la cantidad de elementos de un array no es el indice máximo de ese array.

Creo que esto sería todo. Espero les sirva.