# Warning: Undefined array key 24 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 40

Tags: php, array, date, undefined, warnings

Tengo estos 2 archivos: index.php:

```
        <form action="unidad3.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required><br>
        <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required><br>
        <textarea name="comentario" placeholder="Comentarios" required cols="20" rows="1"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="envio" value="Enviar mensaje">
    </form>
</section>
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        include("comentarios.php");
        
        $txt="comentarios.txt";
        $archivo = fopen($txt, "r") or die("error al abrir el archivo: $txt");

        $vector = file("comentarios.txt");
        $contar_valores = count($vector);

        do {
            echo $vector[$contar_valores];
            $contar_valores--;
        } while ($contar_valores >=0);
        

        fclose($archivo);
    }

?>
```

Y comentarios.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['envio'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y G:i");
    $nombre =  $_POST['nombre'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['comentario'];

    $texto = "<hr>
    <p>Mensaje: $mensaje</p> 
    <p>Correo: $correo</p>
    <p>Nombre completo: $nombre</p>
    <p>Fecha: $fecha</p>
    ";

    $archivo = fopen("comentarios.txt","a+");
    fwrite($archivo, $texto); 
    fclose($archivo);
}
```

?>

Lo que quiero es que a medida que vayan ingresando comentarios, se muestren debajo del formulario. Esto lo logre hacer con un bucle. El problema es que me salta este error **Warning: Undefined array key 24 in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 40** La linea 40 seria la de index.php `echo $vector[$contar_valores];`
Me doy cuenta de que hay un problema con las fechas. El primer comentario no la muestra y en el tercero hay 2 fechas. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo resolverlo ?

Comment: lo que creo es que $vector no lo estas declarando como un array por eso te da error  cuando lo intentas utilizar como tal mas adelante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en que confundes la cantidad de elementos de un array (`count`) con el máximo índice de ese `array[id_max]`.

Mira este ejemplo en la consola:

```php
php > $a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
php > echo count($a);
3
php > echo $a[2];
c
php > echo $a[count($a)];
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 3 in php shell code on line 1
```

Entonces el máximo id de un array ordenado es `count($array) - 1`

Aplicado esto a tu código:

```php
        do {
            echo $vector[$contar_valores-1]; // count() -1
            $contar_valores--;
        } while ($contar_valores > 0); // > 0, porque ya se resta 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Entendí todo y funcionó.